# Run rails code online

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Can any body give me a link to run rails code online?? 
I have tried [codepad.org](http://codepad.org) and [tryruby.org](http://tryruby.org) they are running the ruby code fine 
When I use `Time.now` it gives me correct result but when I try to run like below it give me errors:

`time_ago_in_words(Time.now - 15.hours)`

Thanks

Comment: You need to install Rails locally. Then you can do `rails new`, `cd rails`, `rails server`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `hours` function is specific to Rails, which is a Ruby library. Rails is not loaded in CodePad. You'll have to install Rails on your computer to access those functions. Consult a guide for instructions. [1](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org/) provides an interpreter, but it's geared toward their lessons.